# Contiki-ng Periodic radion on off

Tags: cooja, radio-transmission, contiki-ng, contiki-process

I want to change the radio duty cycle. The radio always stays on and affects energy consumption. I want it to work in a way that it will stay off for 10 seconds and stay on for 10 seconds, how and where should I do this?

I want to change the radio duty cycle. The radio always stays on and affects energy consumption. I want it to work in a way that it will stay off for 10 seconds and stay on for 10 seconds, how and where should I do this